# deep neural network doing wrong predictions on Realtime videos

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, neural-network

I have created a model using TensorFlow for detecting any type of violence in the video. I have trained the model on approx. 2000 videos by splitting it into frames.

But when I use that model on any unseen video or real-time video then it's not predicted correctly.

I just wanted to ask if anyone can tell me I have taken the correct hidden layers and if there are any tweaks I can make for correct predictions.

The `neural_v2.ipynb` is used to train the model. The `test_v2.py` is the file that loads the model and captures videos and predicts.

If you need any more technical clarification please ask me.

If anyone can help in any way, I would really appreciate it.

[Dataset Link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shivam012/violencedetection)

[Code Link](https://github.com/shivam221098/video-surv-new-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you would split your data into three: training, validation, and test (you are using your testing data as your validation).

As @finko's answer, I would try a more epochs, but more importantly a denser model. Experiment with some state of the art models (like VGG16, ResNet152, MobileNet etc). All of these are available as Keras applications (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications).

Comment: Thank you so much. I used VGG16 and trained on 200 epochs. Working better than previous.

Answer (score 0):

You may set the epochs=50 to train again, it will be better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).